# Implement feed with retweets in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, merge

I want to implement retweet feature in my app. I use `Mongoose` and have `User` and `Message` models, and I store retweets as array of objects of type `{userId, createdAt}` where `createdAt` is time when retweet occurred. Message model has it's own `createdAt` field.

I need to create feed of original and retweeted messages merged together based on `createdAt` fields. I am stuck with merging, whether to do it in a single query or separate and do the merge in JavaScript. Can I do it all in Mongoose with a single query? If not how to find merge insertion points and index of the last message?

So far I just have fetching of original messages.

My `Message` model:

```js
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fileId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'File',
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
    likesIds: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    reposts: [
      {
        reposterId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
        },
        createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);
```

Edit: Now I have this but pagination is broken. I am trying to use newCreatedAt field for cursor, that doesn't seem to work. It returns empty array in second call when newCreatedAt is passed from the frontend.

```js
  messages: async (
      parent,
      { cursor, limit = 100, username },
      { models },
    ) => {
      const user = username
        ? await models.User.findOne({
            username,
          })
        : null;

      const options = {
        ...(cursor && {
          newCreatedAt: {
            $lt: new Date(fromCursorHash(cursor)), 
          },
        }),
        ...(username && {
          userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user.id),
        }),
      };

      console.log(options);

      const aMessages = await models.Message.aggregate([
        {
          $addFields: {
            newReposts: {
              $concatArrays: [
                [{ createdAt: '$createdAt', original: true }],
                '$reposts',
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: '$newReposts',
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            newCreatedAt: '$newReposts.createdAt',
            original: '$newReposts.original',
          },
        },
        { $match: options },
        {
          $sort: {
            newCreatedAt: -1,
          },
        },
        {
          $limit: limit + 1,
        },
      ]);

      const messages = aMessages.map(m => {
        m.id = m._id.toString();
        return m;
      });
      //console.log(messages);

      const hasNextPage = messages.length > limit;
      const edges = hasNextPage ? messages.slice(0, -1) : messages; 

      return {
        edges,
        pageInfo: {
          hasNextPage,
          endCursor: toCursorHash(
            edges[edges.length - 1].newCreatedAt.toString(),
          ),
        },
      };
    },
```

Here are the queries. The working one:

```js
Mongoose: messages.aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        createdAt: {
            '$lt': 2020 - 02 - 02 T19: 48: 54.000 Z
        }
    }
}, {
    '$sort': {
        createdAt: -1
    }
}, {
    '$limit': 3
}], {})
```

And the non working one:

```js
Mongoose: messages.aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        newCreatedAt: {
            '$lt': 2020 - 02 - 02 T19: 51: 39.000 Z
        }
    }
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        newReposts: {
            '$concatArrays': [
                [{
                    createdAt: '$createdAt',
                    original: true
                }], '$reposts'
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$newReposts'
}, {
    '$addFields': {
        newCreatedAt: '$newReposts.createdAt',
        original: '$newReposts.original'
    }
}, {
    '$sort': {
        newCreatedAt: -1
    }
}, {
    '$limit': 3
}], {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one query, although its a little hack-ish:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            reposts: {
                $concatArrays: [[{createdAt: "$createdAt", original: true}],"$reports"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$reposts"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            createdAt: "$reposts.createdAt",
            original: "$reposts.original"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            createdAt: -1
        }
    }
]);
```

You can add any other logic you want to the query using the `original` field, documents with `original: true` are the original posts while the others are retweets.

Comment: It's just that my `reposts` field is not array of objects `[{createdAt, reposterId}]` any more but single object `{createdAt, original: true}` https://prnt.sc/qweoth

Comment: I added the code and the queries, can you see whats wrong?

Comment: Is anything matched by `'$lt': 2020 - 02 - 02 T19: 51: 39.000 Z`? its suppose to be `'$lt': ISODate(2020-02-02T19:51:39.000Z)`

Comment: It's just code beautifier i used, the first query has same date format and it is working. Second query returns empty array.

Comment: Except the match query nothing else filters out documents

Comment: i just changed the order and put the $match behind $addFields and it is working. Should I have two $match statements, one on top for username, and second behind $addFields for performance reasons?